# static_assert on an ill-formed-no-diagnostic-required expression

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, static-assert

Is `static_assert` required to fail when processing an *ill-formed-no-diagnostic-required* (IFNDR) expression, or can the compiler ignore it and pass successfully the `static_assert`, as *no diagnostic is required*...?

[The following code](https://godbolt.org/z/Txjsb8Y6W) has some IFNDR cases. GCC, Clang and MSVC differ in their results for the `static_assert`:

```
template<typename T> concept A = T::value || true;
template<typename U> concept B = A<U*>;
template<typename V> concept C = A<V&>;

int main(){
  static_assert(B<int&>); // clang and msvc rejects gcc accepts, ill-formed (int&*)
  static_assert(C<void>); // clang and msvc rejects gcc accepts, ill-formed (void&)
}
```

<sub>The question popped up following this recent interesting question: [C++20 Concepts: Constraint Normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75442605/c20-concepts-constraint-normalization). For explanation and a reference to the spec, regarding concepts-constraint-normalization that create an ill-formed expression follow the above link.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INFDR is, well, IFNDR, **immediately** when the *concept-id* is analyzed.  This isn’t SFINAE, where some sort of context can “capture” the failure and respond to it.

Comment: So it means that in the code above, GCC behavior is valid, the program is ill-formed and you cannot expect anything.